# How to statistically compare the accuracy of different methods?

Tags: error

I have a fairly basic understanding of statistics so I appreciate any help I can get.

I'm trying to compare two different methods (A and B) of placing physical objects accurately. After the objects are placed, the error in placement can be measured. I have collected data with both methods as a list containing the setup displacement error in the three axes (X,Y, and Z) and also absolute magnitude for each data point.

The mean of the displacements is very close to zero for both methods, which I assume means the errors are mostly random. I also computed the RMS average of the absolute displacement to hopefully show the which method is best. Method B's RMS average is nearly half that of Method A's which tells me it's generally more accurate, but I want to really quantify how certain that Method B is better than Method A. What statistical tools are available to do so?

Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Can you clarify which accuracies are you measuring and what methods are you using exactly?

Comment: The collected values are simply measurements in the X, Y, and Z axes representing how far each object was placed from the accepted "perfect" position.

Comment: So it's about comparing distances from a reference point. A t-test or linear model could be used for this.